# Add values from Array to every Object in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

For a project i need to push the values of an array into every object in another array.
What i have so far:

```js
closed_status = [{
    "project_no": 5,
    "priority": 3,
    "s_status": "S8",
    "project_Status: closed"
  },
  {
    "project_no": 8,
    "priority": 1,
    "s_status": "S5",
    "project_Status: closed"
  },
  {
    "project_no": 12,
    "priority": 2,
    "s_status": "S2",
    "project_Status: closed"
  }
]
str = [
  "Value 1",
  "Value 2",
  "Value 3",
]
let result = []
closed_status.forEach((obj) => {
  str.forEach((newValue) => {
    result.push({ ...obj,
      newValue
    })
  })
})
```

...and this is the result i get

```
result = [{
"project_no" : 5,
"priority" : 3,
"s_status": "S8",
"project_Status: closed",
"newValue": "Value 1"
},
{
"project_no" : 5,
"priority" : 3,
"s_status": "S8",
"project_Status: closed",
"newValue": "Value 2"
},
{
"project_no" : 5,
"priority" : 3,
"s_status": "S8",
"project_Status: closed",
"newValue": "Value 3"
},
{
"project_no" : 8,
"priority" : 1,
"s_status": "S5",
"project_Status: closed",
"newValue": "Value 1",
},
{
"project_no" : 8,
"priority" : 1,
"s_status": "S5",
"project_Status: closed",
"newValue": "Value 2",
}]
```

...and so on...
But what i am trying to get is:

```
{
"project_no" : 5,
"priority" : 3,
"s_status": "S8",
"project_Status: closed",
"newValue": "Value 1",
},
{
"project_no" : 8,
"priority" : 1,
"s_status": "S5",
"project_Status: closed",
"newValue": "Value 2",
},
{
"project_no" : 12,
"priority" : 2,
"s_status": "S2",
"project_Status: closed",
"newValue": "Value 3",
},
```

Anyone knows where my mistake is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"Anyone knows where my mistake is?"_ - in making two _nested_ loops, when you should really only be doing _one_ loop?

Comment: What exactly is the difference? I mean, the only difference I see is that the actual result is an array of objects and your expected result is just objects. The values seem to be the same. What am I missing?

Comment: @icebub - my mistake. I tried to edit it but get an error message, that my post is mostly code. The result is an array aswell. With my loop, every value inside my "str" array are pushed into every object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that `closed_status` and `str` always have the same length, which it looks like from your example and wanted result, then you could do the following.

```
for (let i = 0; i < closed_status.length; i++) {
    closed_status[i].newValue = str[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to fill the array of objects with the values of str.

You could do this by keeping track of the index:

```js
closed_status = [{
    "project_no": 5,
    "priority": 3,
    "s_status": "S8",
    "project_Status": "closed"
  },
  {
    "project_no": 8,
    "priority": 1,
    "s_status": "S5",
    "project_Status": 'closed'
  },
  {
    "project_no": 12,
    "priority": 2,
    "s_status": "S2",
    "project_Status": "closed"
  }
]
str = [
  "Value 1",
  "Value 2",
  "Value 3",
]

closed_status.forEach((obj,index) => {
  obj.newValue = str[index]
})

console.log(closed_status)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure `str` and `closed_status`  have the same amount of items, you could use `str.shift()` to shift out a single value that you spread into the original object.

```js
closed_status = [
  {
    "project_no": 5,
    "priority": 3,
    "s_status": "S8",
    "project_Status": "closed"
  },
  {
    "project_no": 8,
    "priority": 1,
    "s_status": "S5",
    "project_Status": "closed"
  },
  {
    "project_no": 12,
    "priority": 2,
    "s_status": "S2",
    "project_Status": "closed"
  }
]
str = [
  "Value 1",
  "Value 2",
  "Value 3",
]

closed_status = closed_status.map(e => ({ ...e, newValue: str.shift() }) );
console.log(closed_status);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution assumes the first array is longer than the second. However, the lengths are always the same then `i < str.length ? i : i % str.length` can be replaced by `i`.

```js
const
closed_status = [{
    "project_no": 5,
    "priority": 3,
    "s_status": "S8",
    "project_Status": "closed"
  },
  {
    "project_no": 8,
    "priority": 1,
    "s_status": "S5",
    "project_Status": "closed"
  },
  {
    "project_no": 12,
    "priority": 2,
    "s_status": "S2",
    "project_Status": "closed"
  }
],
str = [
  "Value 1",
  "Value 2",
  "Value 3",
],
result = closed_status
.map((status,i) => ({...status, newValue:str[i < str.length ? i : i % str.length]}));

console.log( result );

//alternatively, (EQUAL LENGTHS)
console.log( str.map((newValue,i) => ({...closed_status[i],newValue})) );
```